# При тестировании GUI элемент появляется и исчезает слишком быстро

Tags: coffeescript, mocha

Я тестирую GUI с помощью средств **Webdriver.io** и **mocha**. Сами тесты пишутся на языке **CoffeeScript**. Некоторые элементы интерфейса подгружаются достаточно долго, при этом появляется вращающийся индикатор загрузки. Для того, чтобы продолжить процесс тестирования, необходимо дождаться полной загрузки данных (то есть дождаться исчезновения индикатора загрузки). Этот процесс выполнялся с помощью функции **(1)**:

```
wait_for_page_load = () ->
  $('... селектор индикатора загрузки ...').waitForDisplayed(20000)
  $('... селектор индикатора загрузки ...').waitForDisplayed(20000, true)
```

В первой строчке я ожидаю момента, когда индикатор загрузки становится видимым. Во второй сроке я ожидаю исчезновение индикатора загрузки.

Однако в процессе работы я столкнулся с ситуацией, при которой индикатор загрузки появляется и исчезает слишком быстро. При этом я просто не успеваю "поймать" индикатор загрузки, потому что в тот момент, когда я ожидаю его появления, он уже исчезает. При этом в консоль выводится сообщение об ошибке:

```
element ("... селектор индикатора загрузки ...") still not displayed after 20000ms
```

Я выкрутился и из этой ситуации, пусть и не совсем честно (по моему мнению). При возникновении подобной проблемы я фиксировал только исчезновение индикатора загрузки. Этот процесс выполнялся с помощью функции **(2)**:

```
wait_for_page_load = () ->
  $('... селектор индикатора загрузки ...').waitForDisplayed(20000, true)
```

*Нужно заметить, что при быстром исчезновении индикатора загрузки обойтись совсем без ожидания тоже не получается - в этом случае новые данные не успеют загрузиться.*

Однако в некоторых ситуациях я не могу точно определить заранее, как долго индикатор загрузки будет видимым: иногда он исчезает практически сразу, и я не могу отследить момент его появления, в этих случаях приходится использовать функцию **(2)**; иногда он вращается долгое время, и отследить момент его появления можно с помощью функции **(1)**.

Можно ли написать универсальную функцию, которая будет фиксировать появление и исчезновение графического элемента, даже если элемент появляется и исчезает очень быстро?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока что я нашел следующий способ решения проблемы. В ситуациях, когда необходимо дождаться исчезновения индикатора загрузки, я сначала выдерживаю таймаут в одну секунду, а затем ожидаю исчезновение индикатора загрузки.

```
utilities.wait_for_page_load = () ->
  browser.pause(1000)
  $('... селектор индикатора загрузки ...').waitForDisplayed(20000, true)
```

Таким образом, если индикатор загрузки появился и исчез слишком быстро, то по окончании таймаута его уже не будет на экране, соответственно, мы автоматически дождались исчезновения индикатора загрузки. Если же индикатор загрузки висит на экране долгое время, то по окончании таймаута мы просто продолжаем ожидать его исчезновения.

Метод неидеальный. Основной его недостаток - увеличение общего времени выполнения тестов. Однако, метод универсальный и позволяет обработать обе ситуации, описанные в вопросе.